# <P> text is outside of it's block boundary

Tags: html, css

Please see the code below. When I opened the page in the browser, I see that the text of the paragraph is well outside of its box boundary.

I read somewhere that a floated element is ignored by other element in "normal flow". In this case, the `<p>` should behave as if the div wasn't there. The position of the paragraph's borders kind of supports that idea, but its text is outside of the borders instead of at the top left corner.

It doesn't seem like a bug as it behaves the same in IE11, Firefox and Chrome. Is this behavior specified by any HTML standard? Thanks!

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="border: solid 5px; width: 200px; height: 200px; float:left"></div>
    <p style="border:solid red 5px;width:100px;height:100px;">hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: thanks for the responses people! But I wasn't intending to ask for the method to place the paragraph text in the  div. I just want to know why the paragraph border is contained in the div, while its text is outside. This layout concept just doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div style="border: solid 5px; width: 200px; height: 200px; float:left">
    <p style="border:solid red 5px;width:100px;height:100px;">
         hello world
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used `<p>` tag outside the `<div>` tag.
you have to write the `<p>` tag before you close `</div>` so that it remains inside the box

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border: solid 5px; width: 200px; height: 200px; float:left">
        <p style="border:solid red 5px;width:100px;height:100px;">hello world</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happens because by default `p` and `div` both are blocked level element. and both elements start from `top` and `left` direction.

As you give the `float:left` property to div it floated left however it doesn't appear the div is floated. There are few ways and one of them is using `position`.

you can fixed it by using `position:absolute;`

```
div{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:10px;
}
```

Here is the working ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hawalina/1/)***.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `hello world` text inside the `div`, you should use para inside the `div`. if the para outside the `div` then it will display outside the div. you no need to use `float:left;`

```
--div
  --p
    hello world
```

Your code structure should be

```
<div style="border: solid 5px; width: 200px; height: 200px;">    
  <p style="border:solid red 5px;width:100px;height:100px;">hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above shared by Aishvarya karthik is correct but you can optimise furthur by removing `float:left` property as you not need to use that as output remain the same

```
 <div style="border: solid 5px; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
     <p style="border:solid red 5px;width:100px;height:100px;">hello world</p>
 </div>
```